# Differnce between putting Files outside root and give 400 File Permission?

Tags: file, ftp, security

I have all my key files outside root directory, where it cannot be accessed by the public, however, how is this method superior to simply giving these key files 400 file permission in the ftp? (no read, write, execute permission for Group and Public, only read permission for Owner.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By placing them in a completely separate directory it makes it a lot harder to accidentaly change the permissions to something insecure.

For example, when uploading something else and changing the permissions of that; if the key files were in the same directory it is possible that you might select them also by mistake.